# Checking out into a separate directory without affecting the current repo

Tags: git

I want to check out a past commit into a separate directory and I don't want the current repo to be affected by that at all.

Making a clone and checking out there does the job, but it seems like an overkill. Setting GIT_WORK_TREE or --work-tree fails to leave the current repo alone (although it does check out elsewhere, it still updates HEAD, and I don't want that).

Is there a better way?

Comment: May I ask what you plan on doing with this checked out code?  If all you want are the files themselves you could just checkout the commit in the detached state and then cut-and-paste the entire directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git worktree` for this.

```
git worktree add ../other-worktree <old-commit-id>
```

This is lets you have an independent working tree attached to the original repository. Once you're done you can simply remove the new directory.

See [git help worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for full details.

Before `git worktree` you could have done something like this, but I don't see any reason not to use `git worktree` now. It's simpler and less error prone:

```
( GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) &&
    export GIT_INDEX_FILE &&
    git read-tree "$old-commit-id$ &&
    git checkout-index -a --prefix=../old-commit-copy/ &&
    rm "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
)
```